# Brightness/contrast changing in RGB space

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

if I have two RGB-images (from digital camera) for the same object in diffrents lighting conditions (With/Without flash light, High/Low light source...). If we could approximate the change between these images to just Brightness and Contrast like this:

```
Image_1 = A*Images_2 + B
```

In order to find those A,B, an algorithm was applied.

**The question:**

Should this Algorithm be applied on each channel separately which leads to obtain three different pairs of (A,B) like this:

```
Find (A_r,B_r) that Minimize [R(Image_1)  -  A_r*R(Image_2)  + B_r]
Find (A_g,B_g) that Minimize [G(Image_1)  -  A_g*G(Image_2)  + B_g]
Find (A_b,B_b) that Minimize [B(Image_1)  -  A_b*B(Image_2)  + B_b]
```

Or it should be applied on the 3 channels in the same time and find just 1 pair of (A,B) which gives the best solution like this:

```
Find (A,B) that Minimize:
            [R(Image_1)  -  A* R(Image_2)  + B]
            [G(Image_1)  -  A* G(Image_2)  + B]
            [B(Image_1)  -  A* B(Image_2)  + B]
```

Comment: I'd go with each channel separately, better in hsv,  lab, or basically any other color space except rgb

Comment: I'm very interested in the results of both approaches. Do you have some test images to share?

Comment: @Miki Thanks.. Can you support your decision with any clear reference or reason?

Comment: @Eliezer I will try to share the test results after finishing the implementation

Comment: No, sorry. Or I've written an answer :D. It's just that brightness and contrast have not much to do with color, so I'd work in some color space that separates the color information from the intensity, luminance, etc... And for this reason I'd work on each separate channel. For example in hsv you don't want to mess to much with hue channel, but probably much more with value and saturation. That said, I'm not an expert in color theory, so I might be wrong :D

Comment: @Miki.. I see. it is logical..Thanks